# Some problems when changing CSS position with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, position

I'm working on a really simple project which consist of a grid of images. When an image is clicked, it expands a `<div>` with some content and also scrolls the window, thanks to several variable calculation (not sure if I'm doing this the best way posible), in order to place the `<div>` with the content right below the header. This expanded `<div>`contains some navigation buttons; next, previous and close. I'm trying to keep the close button always visible even if we scroll down the content. I do this by changing the CSS position from `absolute` to `fixed` with this function:

```
$(function () {

            var winD = $(window);
            var pos = distanceItemBt;

            winD.scroll(function(){
                if (winD.scrollTop() <= pos ){
                    $('.buttons .btn-close').css({position: 'absolute',  top: 10});
                } else {
                    $('.btn-close').css({position: 'fixed',  top: 65});
                }

            });

  });
```

But it doesn't work always as expected doing some random changes plus it affects the position I place the `<div>` right below the header.

Here you is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/35j2tu6p/

I'm not sure if I'm not getting the right variables or missing any calculation that will do everything easier and working always the same way.

I begging for some help because I don't know what else to try tbh.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the inconvenience.